# Git: how to commit changes as if it were a merge with another branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

Consider 2 branches in a project: `branch1`, `branch2`.

I was working on the branch1. Then another developer commited changes to the `branch2`.

I wanted to merge his changes from `branch2` to `branch1` but the auto-merge was impossible, so I copied all the changes myself. Now I want to commit, but I need Git to know it is actually a merge commit. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try to merge using a non-default strategy ? ie: `git merge -X theirs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stash the changes:

```
git stash
```

Then merge without committing (`--no-commit`) and set merge strategy to `ours` which do not copy any changes from another branch:

```
git merge MERGEBRANCH -s ours --no-commit
```

Then get back your changes:

```
git stash apply
```

Now you can commit. It will be a merge commit.